# Adding Azure Mobile Service system properties columns to tables

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I have an existing Azure Mobile Services data table that I would like to manually add [system properties columns](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/11/23/new-tables-in-azure-mobile-services-string-id-system-properties-and-optimistic-concurrency.aspx) to.  When I try to do an update I get an error:

> Error: The value of property '__version' is of type 'object' which is
>   not a supported type.

This doesn't seem to happen on tables that are created through the portal or CLI.  Is there a trick to getting this work?  Here's a custom table I've created manually:

```
CREATE TABLE [my_test](
    [id] bigint NOT NULL identity,
    [__createdAt] [datetimeoffset](3) NOT NULL,
    [__updatedAt] [datetimeoffset](3) NULL,
    [__version] [timestamp] NOT NULL,   
    [name] [nvarchar](max) NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)

GO

ALTER TABLE [my_test] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_my_test___createdAt]  DEFAULT (CONVERT([datetimeoffset](3),sysutcdatetime(),(0))) FOR [__createdAt]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

When I just created a new service the __version column is of type "rowversion" and id is an nvarchar(255). 
I'd try those two changes and see if it works for you.
Note that both are not null so you will have trouble changing this if you have existing data.